# Customizing item-text in v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Please tell me if we can customize `item-text` for `v-select` ?

I want customize each item in `v-select`, something like this :

```
:item-text="item.name - item.description"
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yes you can, using `scoped slot` as described in the doc and provide a `template`.

For `v-select` you have two `scoped slot` :

- `selection` : to describe how `v-select` should render items when selected
- `item` : to describe how `v-select` should render items when opened

It looks like this :

```
<v-select> // Don't forget your props
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    <!-- HTML that describe how select should render selected items -->
    {{ data.item.name }} - {{ data.item.description }}
  </template>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    <!-- HTML that describe how select should render items when the select is open -->
    {{ data.item.name }} - {{ data.item.description }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

[CodePen with a complex example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBBJGr?&editors=101)

[Vuetify Doc about Scoped Slot in V-Select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-scoped-slots)

---

**Edit for Vuetify 1.1.0+** : Those slots are also available with new components `v-autocomplete` and `v-combobox` as they inherit from `v-select`.

---

**Edit for Vue 2.6+**, replace :

- `slot="selection" slot-scope="data"` by `v-slot:selection="data"`
- `slot="item" slot-scope="data"` by `v-slot:item="data"`

Comment: Must have both `slot` and `slot-scope` attributes for the `template` tag. This wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: should be `<template v-slot:item="data">` as of vue 2.6

Comment: it works fine, but having the multiple attribute, you loose the checkbox on each option

Comment: You have to handle it @MCSI

Comment: You can do it like this:

```
<template v-slot:item="data">
                <v-list-item-action>
                  <v-icon v-if="data.attrs.inputValue">check_box</v-icon>
                  <v-icon v-else>check_box_outline_blank</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-action>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>
                    {{ data.item.text }} - {{ data.item.description }}
                  </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
</template>
``

Answer (score 65):

Shorthand :

```
:item-text="item => item.name +' - '+ item.description"
```

Comment: Thanks, we can also write this as                                                                                             ```:item-text="item =>`${item.name} - ${item.description}`" ```

Comment: The only oslution that worked for me, as I wanted this for a 'multiple' select - is there any chance that I can also sort the tiems based on the custom item-text?

Comment: @Inigo  Actually this is another question, check v-select `filter` props, it accepts a function with `itemText`

Comment: While the accepted answer worked for me already, I do like this one more, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the best practices

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer

Comment: This also works with `:item-value` which I needed.

Answer (score 43):

Slot removes autoselect on focus.

`item-text` tye can be: `string | array | function`

then we can make:

```
:item-text="text"
```

and

```
methods: {
  text: item => item.name + ' — ' + item.description
}
```

Comment: and the question is: what does the array type mean?

Comment: @P.Scheit, `.join(',')` alias. [Just try](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kradbe?&editors=101)

Comment: ``:item-value`` can also be used to set the selected value.

Answer (score 29):

Here's an example in simple following code:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    label="Names"
    v-model="name"
    :items="names"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
    return-object
  >
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
      {{ getText(item) }}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      {{ getText(item) }}
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script> 
export default {
  data: () => ({
    names: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Paul', age: 23 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Marcelo', age: 15 },
      { id: 3, name: 'Any', age: 30 },
    ],
    name: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    getText(item) => `${item.name} - ${item.text}`,
  },
}   
</script>
```

The following is the reference:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#advanced-slots

Comment: Nice example. Thank you

Comment: The `v-slot:selection` is not working in my case. I am using vue3 composition api

Answer (score 6):

**Vuetify 3.0.0 Update**

If you decide to use a template:

in Vuetify 3.0.0 there is a breaking change, which is not yet documented. In this version the `v-list-item` is not generated by default. So you have to create it by yourself. You need to add it as follows:

```
<v-select :items="mylist" item-title="name" item-value="id">
    <template #selection="{ item }">
        <span><img :src="item.raw.image" />  {{item.raw.name}}</span>
    </template>
    <template #item="{ item, props }">
        <v-list-item v-bind="props">
            <template #title>
                <span><img :src="item.raw.image" /> {{item.raw.name}}</span>
            </template>
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>

data () {
    return {
        mylist: [
            {id:0, image:"pic1.png", name:"Entry1"},
            {id:1, image:"pic2.png", name:"Entry2"},
            {id:2, image:"pic3.png", name:"Entry3"},
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be much higher. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way, no slots and minimal logic. You probably want to use `item-title` instead.

```
<v-select
   :item-title="(item)=>`${item.name}-${item.description}`"
   v-model="selectedItem"
   :items="items"/>
```

Comment: Most concise solution here, should be answer

Answer (score 0):

in case you don't want to deal with slots or other methods to manipulate item-text. here is another different approach to achieve the same result.

simply add a new 'displayname' key: value pair to your v-model collection on the fly with a computed method and use it as the v-model for the select and the new key as the item-text

```js
computed: {
  addDisplayname() {
    return names.map(v => ({ ...v,
      displayname: v.name + ' - ' + v.description
    }))
  }
}
```