# Make v-select html conversion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use axios to send data to v-select, but the content is in html format.

I want to use v-html to convert text but it is unsuccessful.

```
<v-select
 :items="quizs"
 item-text="questiontext"
 item-value="id"
 v-model="quizid"
></v-select>
```

[image: My code picture]

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531864/customizing-item-text-in-v-select link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use template inside v-select for your custom display. Then use v-html to decode html tags as below :

```
<v-select :items='quizs' v-model="quizid">
    <template v-slot:item='{item}'>
         <div v-html='item.questiontext'/>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:selection='{item}'>
         <div v-html='item.questiontext'/>
    </template>
</v-select>
```