# Vue v-select problem with v-slot not showing text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm trying to display custom text in v-select options by slots.

Template:

```html
<v-select v-model="dLevelSelected" :items="dLevels" solo>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    <span>{{data.description}}</span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Script:

```
data () {
  return {
    dLevelSelected: null,
    dLevels: [{id:1, value: 1, description: 'Level1'}, {id:2, value: 2, description: 'Level2'}]
  }
}
```

With this, when you open the v-select the two registers of dLevels are appearing as boxes but with any text. It seems like the data.description is being evaluated like data.undefined

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76866087/13935477

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-deprecated) and [`slot-scope`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-scope-deprecated) are deprecated as of Vue 2.6.0.

The new slot syntax combines those two props into [`v-slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot), so the equivalent [`item` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-item) is:

```html
<template v-slot:item="scope">
  <span>{{ scope.item.description }}</span>
</template>
```

Note the `scope` contains an `item` property that can be used to access `description`. You can use object destructuring to simplify that to:

```html
<template v-slot:item="{ item }">
  <span>{{ item.description }}</span>
</template>
```

Similarly, you'll probably want a custom [`selection` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-selection) that renders the appearance of the selected item:

```html
<template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
  <span>{{ item.description }} ({{ item.value }})</span>
</template>
```

The final template should look similar to this:

```html
<v-select v-model="dLevelSelected" :items="dLevels" solo>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <span>{{ item.description }}</span>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
    <span>{{ item.description }} ({{ item.value }})</span>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-cusotm-item-slot-for-v-select?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)